# Serving Files Through Spring Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a small server that has couple of .exe/.zip files in the src/main/resources

I would like to serve these files through my service.

What I have tried is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Context extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("resources/**")
                 .addResourceLocation("classpath:/");

    }
}
```

This works fine but the problem is that I am unable to set content type on the files. I.e. when I access .zip files the binary code is rendered as text in browser. Is there a way to set content type based on file extension?

Also Is there a way to setup a simple forwarding (expose particular folder with files) without creating a controller. Unless controller would be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your **web.xml**

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>zip</extension>
    <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>exe</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-msdownload</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```